# Install doker without admin rights

Tags: windows-10, administration

I try to install doker in universty's PC but I don't have admin permission  , I searched a  zip file to install it but no way , so do you have an idea to make it , I used windows 10 as OS .

Thanks.

Comment: Ask your IT department.

Comment: If you can install any software/application without admin rights, the admin rights are useless. It's there and supposed to prevent people from installing everything they want to the PC.

Comment: My question is if there is a zip installation for docker ?

Comment: Considering how docker needs to interacts with the hardware - most likely not. Why not ask your IT department for admin rights?

Comment: *docker... there is no "portable" installation option - due to the underlying virtual machine, you'll need admin rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "*portable*" installation option for Docker on any platform.

Docker relies on a Virtual Machine on the Windows / Mac platforms:

- Such a VM cannot be run without a VirtualBox installation.
- You cannot install VirtualBox without administrator rights

Docker relies on root access on a Linux machine.

---

An important note from [RedGrittyBrick](https://superuser.com/users/52492/redgrittybrick)'s answer (before it was deleted):

> As I'm sure you know, if you are using someone elses equipment for a purpose they didn't intend then you are jeopardising your relationship with the owner. At a minumum it is unprofessional conduct, at worst it can result in expulsion, termination or criminal prosecution. It is generally best, for your future career, to go through the appropriate channels to get the application approved by the IT department.

Comment: So I asked Department IT and I get Ok to install it .... thank's